# 100% height minus nPx via css or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

i am trying to make my main content div 100% height base on browser windows size but i want it will start after header. i am getting 100% height but it is start from top but i want it will leave header are then it will 100% height.  bellow is code.

mainly i want to make my **contentarea** div will cover 100% width and height but minus will be **header** height

```
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
body {
    background-color: #F90;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #36F;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #FF3300;
    opacity: 0.3;
    z-index: 5;
}
.contentarea {
    background-color: #396;

    z-index: 2;

}
</style>

<script>
jQuery(function($){

    //Fix height of the slider wraper
    $(window).on('resize', function(){

        var h = $(this).height() - $('header').height();
        if(h<=200) h=200
        $('#home').height(h); 


    }).trigger('resize');
});
</script>


<header>
  <div class="companyname"> sdf </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Space Available</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Parking / Amenities</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="contentarea" id="home">adasdasdasdas
  adsada

  dasdasdas
  <div class="footer">copy right</div>
</div>
```

demo  http://jsfiddle.net/o0Lcrv3w/

i already search some in here and got many solution, many post i tried with those but not really work any yet.

like

```
height: -o-calc(100% - 100px); /* opera */
height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px); /* google, safari */
height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px); /* firefox */
```

Comment: didn't you achieved it?

Comment: i did that way how @Hassan Baig said. but i wanted  do something in  js. because header height can be change.

Comment: can't you do something like `$("#home").height($(window).height()-$("header").height()-$("footer").height())`?

Comment: nor properly work that way. anyway thanks for your tips. i will try again this

Answer (score 1):

Update Content area class as:

```
.contentarea {
background-color: #396;position:relative; z-index:2;
top:100px;bottom:0px;}
```

You can check it at http://jsfiddle.net/o0Lcrv3w/2/

Comment: thanks. currently i fixed your way.. but i didn't want do by css position top etc. i wanted via js mainly. thank u so much

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the body 100% height and put the header inside it like this:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  padding-top: 100px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/91qwq6rn/

Comment: thanks.. this is new way i know it didn't come in mind . thanks.